# Импорт библиотеки в импортируемом классе Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться. Есть похожие вопросы, но точного ответа найти не смог.

Есть класс в файле my_class.py

```
class Get_data():
   def __init__(self):
      pass
   def connection(self):

      params = urllib.parse.quote_plus(
            'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
            +f'SERVER=server;'
            +f'Database=database;'
            +f'Trusted_Connection=No;'
            +f'UID=uid;'
            +f'PWD=pass'
      #do smth
```

И есть файл file_1.py в который класс импортируется

```
import urllib
sys.path.append(r'C:\Users\User\my_folder')
from my_class import Get_data

gd=Get_data()
gd.connection()
```

Выполнение file_1.py приводит к

> NameError: name 'urllib' is not defined

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Вы импортировали в файл ```my_class.py``` модуль ```urllib```?

Comment: Я хотел, чтобы создавая экземпляр класс Get_data из файла my_class.py достаточно было бы импортировать urlli только один раз.

Comment: @Thistle какую проблему вы таким образом пытаетесь решить? В Zen of Python есть такое утверждение: явное лучше неявного. Так и здесь, лучше в каждом конкретном модуле указывать именно те импорты, которые он использует, а не пытаться спрятать импорты в каком-то отдельном модуле ради непонятно чего (экономии строк что ли?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы должны импортировать модуль urllib в том файле, который его использует. Поскольку целевой файл не имеет этого модуля, Вам и выдается ошибка.